# Android View Overlapping

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to overlap the circle text "100" over shirt image by half of the circle. Half  of the circle need to overlap with image and half below image, such that it aligns with "Add" button on the right of the image.

[image]

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/productImage"
        android:src="@mipmap/sample" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add "
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:background="@color/royal_blue"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/productImage"
        android:layout_margin="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/blue_badge_price"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="100"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:minWidth="80dp"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/productImage"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I am clueless.. how to do it.

Comment: please add expected reference image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative `marginTop` for your `TextView`.
Add:

```
android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
```

(`-50dp` because its negative half of the `TextView's` `height`)